# How to compute the Fourier transform of this function?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

In our course, the Fourier transform of $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as,
$$\mathcal{F}(f) = \hat{f}(\zeta) = \int e^{-ix\zeta}f(x)dx.$$
Therefore, the inverse fourier transform is defined as,
$$\bar{\mathcal{F}}(f) = f(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{ix\zeta} \hat{f}(\zeta)d\zeta.$$
Furthermore, we know that,
$$\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+x^2}\right) = 2\pi e^{-\alpha|\zeta|}.$$
My goal is to compute $$\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{x+i}\right).$$
Here is what I have tried so far. For $\alpha =1$ we get that,
$$\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{x+i}\cdot \frac{1}{x-i}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{x+i}\right)*\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{x-i}\right) =\pi e^{-|\zeta|}.$$
Now if 
$$\hat{f}(\zeta) = \mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{x+i}\right)$$ 
then,
$$\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{x-i}\right) = \hat{f}(-\zeta).$$
Thus we want to solve 
$$\hat{f}(x)*\hat{f}(-x) = 2\pi^2 e^{-|\zeta|}.$$
I am not sure how to proceed after this step. Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: There is the small problem that $\frac{1}{x+i}\notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$. But putting that aside as there are ways to regularize, undoing a convolution is fairly hard. More or less the only strategy I'm aware of is by inspection, i.e. lots and lots of intuition and practice.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, that's true. So I guess I have to use the definition of the Fourier Transform for $L^2.$ But I am not sure how to carry out further manipulations.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173821/the-fourier-transform-of-frac1x). Eventually they reach the conclusion that $\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2i}\operatorname{sgn}(\zeta)$. Then use the Fourier translation property to get that $\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{x\pm i}\right) = \frac{\pi e^{\mp \zeta}}{2i}\operatorname{sgn}(\zeta)$

Comment: @Ninad: That cannot be true. The function $1/(x \pm i)$ is in $L^2$, but the function that you claim to be it's Fourier transform is not.